# API management/proxy: worth it for UI-consumed API calls/internal API calls?

Tags: wso2, enterprise, apigee, wso2-api-manager

Are products like Wso2/Apigee and other "api management"/api proxy tools worth using (and do people actually use them) in the following two cases:

1. API calls that are exclusively called by the UI of web-app
2. API's consumed by small numbers of systems inside a company i.e. no external users

I know the general use case of these tools is for managing external developers access to API's designed to share data/functionality with the outside.

While some features of api management tools might be irrelevant in the case of UI-called API calls and internal API calls, i am wondering if there may be a value to using them to gather metrics on calls made from the UI or internal users/apps.

Wondering if anyone actually uses api management tools for these purposes.

Comment: It depends entirely on what you're doing. Do you require analytics? Do you require out of the box products like OAuth to work? Do you have developers willing to maintain an internal API? That said, not really an appropriate question for StackOverflow. You'd be better to do some market research.

Comment: An API management platform enforces rules and adds a layer of orchestration between the consumer and the backend services. As long as you need those, a facade layer like Apigee is a good idea.